# How do you move an Excel worksheet from one workbook into another using openxlsx in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to take input from 3 separate Excel files, do some work with them in R, and return all three Excel files, as well as my calculations, as a single Excel file. Obviously this can be done manually (and is probably safer that way), but I'd like to automate it if possible.

I've been using the openxlsx package, which works really well for reading in a single workbook and then appending the work I've done in R, but I can't figure out how to move sheets from one workbook object to another. I tried:

```
 wb1 <- loadWorkbook("hi.xlsx")
 wb2 <- loadWorkbook("bye.xlsx")
 wb2[[2]] <- wb1[[1]]
```

And a few other things, but nothing seemed to work. I have noted that:

```
 names(wb1)
```

Will give the names of the worksheets in wb1, but there doesn't seem to be a way to move worksheets around. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Sorry--I should have been more clear. I want to read in the sheet with all of its original formatting and write it to the new file. Using read.xlsx loses all of the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `xlsx` package:

```
library(xlsx)
wb1 <- read.xlsx("Workbook1.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1)
wb2 <- read.xlsx("Workbook2.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1)
write.xlsx(wb1, "Workbook Joined.xlsx")
write.xlsx(wb2, "Workbook Joined.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet2", append = T)
```

Comment: Sorry--I should have been more clear. I want to read in the sheet with all of its original formatting and write it to the new file. Using read.xlsx loses all of the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work as follows (mind you: this only works for sheets with data):

```
 wb1 <- loadWorkbook("hi.xlsx")
 wb2 <- loadWorkbook("bye.xlsx")

lapply(sheets(wb2), function(s) {
    
  dt <- read.xlsx("bye.xlsx", sheet = s)
  addWorksheet(wb1, sheetName = s)
  writeData(wb1, s, dt)

})
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example how to use read.xlsx function to read data from excel files

```
 read.xlsx(xlsxFile, sheet = 1, startRow = 1, colNames = TRUE,
      rowNames = FALSE, detectDates = FALSE, skipEmptyRows = TRUE,
      rows = NULL, cols = NULL, check.names = FALSE, namedRegion = NULL)
```

sheet indicates The name or index of the sheet to read data from.

Comment: Sorry--I should have been more clear. I want to read in the sheet with all of its original formatting and write it to the new file. Using read.xlsx loses all of the formatting.